# LINQ query performance

Tags: performance, linq-to-entities

I have some tables that are connected between them in a primary key-foreign key one to many relation. For example tables books and authors. A book can have one author and every author can have many books. If I have the book object and I need to use its author's properties, is it better performance to drill down everytime in the code, or should I pull the author object and use its properties?

I hope my question is clear, it suppose to be easy I assume but I don't have anybody to ask.

Comment: If you have a performance related question sometimes the best thing to do is get your hands dirty by implementing both options and timing them. Then you have solid objective evidence that is directly related to your problem/domain.

Comment: @IanNewson:  yes you are right sometimes this is the best way and I use it sometimes. It's just that I was wondering if there is a rule that I can I follow in the scenrio I have..

Answer (score 0):

Just use the code that most clearly and concisely expresses what you want to achieve. The performance will depend many factors but probably already will be satisfactory.

Later, in case an actual performance problem appears, you can reason more clearly about performance because you will know the actual numbers (i.e. number of books, authors, modify and read rates for each, available RAM, CPU load, database server load, network load) involved.